# Forward Euler Method for $dx/dt=2x-4+4t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the initial value problem $\frac{dx}{dt}=2x-4+4t$ with initial condition $x(0)=3/2$ and i need to use the forward euler method with a time step of $0.1$ up to $t=0.5$.

I have that the equation for the forward euler method $x_{n+1}=x_n +dt*(2*(x_n)-4+4*(t_n))$. Where $dt=0.1$.

From the intial condition $x=3/2$ when $t=0$ but if i apply these conditions for $x_1$ I get:

$x_1=x_0+0.1(2*x_0-4+4*t_0)$,

$x_1=1.5+0.1(2*1.5-4+4*0)$,

$x_1=1.5-0.1$,

$x_1=1.4$.

But surely that can't be right as for $t=0$ there are two values of $x$: $x_0=1.5, x_1=1.4$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: $x_1 \neq x_0$ your partition is $x_0=0,x_1=.1,x_2=.2,x_3=.3,x_4=.4,x_5=0.5$ so you do not have two value for $t=0$

Comment: seems correct.compute $x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$.

Comment: I get $x_2=1.32, x_3=1.264, x_4=1.2368, x_5=1.2442$. Is that correct? I'm confused so do you not use $t=0.5$ at all when calculating from $0$ to $0.5$ in $0.1$ timesteps?

Comment: Yes, these numbers are correct. -- And that is the forward Euler method for you, other methods use more intermediate times, see the Heun method or the classical RK4.

Comment: In the future, please, add additional facts that you discover as part of the solution to the question text. Mark the additions with a date like a log book to leave the relation of question and answer less confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Your value $x_1$ is for the time $t_1=t_0+dt=0.1$. Everything else is correct

You should be getting $x_{10}=2.09586821124$.

---

*(2 days later, nov20)* 
**The exact solution** is of the form $x(t)=Ae^{2t}+Bt+C$, inserting into the equation gives $B=−2$ and $C=1$ for the particular solution, the initial value then $\frac32=x(0)=A+1$ gives $A=\frac12$.

---

**In `Python` one can implement** the task for different step sizes as

```
def EulerF(g,t,x,tf,dt):
    while t<tf-dt: x+= dt*g(t,x); t+=dt
    return x+(tf-t)*g(t,x)

g = lambda t,x: 2*x-4+4*t

t0 =0.0; x0 = 1.5; tf=0.5
xexact = lambda t : 1-2*t+(x0-1)*(exp(2*t)-1)

for h in [ 0.1, 0.01, 0.001 ]: 
  for dt in [h,h/2, h/5]:
    xapp = EulerF(g,t0,x0,tf,dt)
    xexa = xexact(tf)
    print "dt=%10.6f x=%10.6f x-xe=%10.6f =dt*%.6f" %(dt, xapp, xapp-xexa, (xapp-xexa)/dt)
```

This gives the following table of results, which clearly demonstrates convergence towards the exact value, but also that this convergence is rather slow as an order 1 method, the relative error being close to the step size.

```
dt=  0.100000 x=  1.244160 x-xe= -0.114981 =dt*-1.149809
dt=  0.050000 x=  1.296871 x-xe= -0.062270 =dt*-1.245394
dt=  0.020000 x=  1.332918 x-xe= -0.026223 =dt*-1.311137
dt=  0.010000 x=  1.345794 x-xe= -0.013347 =dt*-1.334690
dt=  0.005000 x=  1.352407 x-xe= -0.006734 =dt*-1.346800
dt=  0.002000 x=  1.356433 x-xe= -0.002708 =dt*-1.354176
dt=  0.001000 x=  1.357784 x-xe= -0.001357 =dt*-1.356654
dt=  0.000500 x=  1.358462 x-xe= -0.000679 =dt*-1.357896
dt=  0.000200 x=  1.358869 x-xe= -0.000272 =dt*-1.358643
```

Comment: how would you find out the true solution for an equation like this to compare to my numerical solution?

Comment: This is a linear ODE with constant coefficients and exponential-type right side (even if the exponential $e^{0·x}$ is trivial). Thus you get $x(t)=Ae^{2t}+Bt+C$ as the general form of the solution which you need now to insert into the equation and initial condition to fix its coefficients.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck with this, I know that if i sub in $x=0, t=0$ then you end up with $0=A+C$, but i'm not sure how you get a second equation, do you differentiate $x(t)=Ae^2t + Bt+C$ to get $\frac{dx}{dt}=2Ae^2x+Bx$? but then i'm not sure how to use this to get another equation to solve the coefficients.

Comment: Yes, you get $2Ae^{2t}+B=\dot x = 2(Ae^{2t}+Bt+C)+4t-4$ and compare to find $0=2B+4$ and $B=2C-4$.

Comment: I find that $A=-1, B=-2$ and $C=1$ giving the true solution as $x=-e^{2t}-2t+1$ but then this gives that the numerical solution is very different from the true solution, as the true solution gives this curve https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=for+t%3D0+to+t%3D0.5+plot+x%3D-e%5E(2t)+-+2t%2B1,

Comment: The error of Euler is $O(h)$, in this case this means that the error at $t=0.5$ is about $2.5·h$, or an relative error of about $h$, if you check different smaller step sizes. At $h=0.1$ this will be rather large.

Comment: at t=0.5 the error is around 4, is this not too large? as i have that the true solution at this point is -e^1 and the numerical solution is 1.2442.

Comment: How did you get $A=-1$? For $x(0)=1.5$ you should get $A=x(0)-C=0.5$.

Comment: just realised i used x(0)=0, so that is why. I've figured it out and looks much more similar!